# webpack external css -> image missing leads to error, how to ignore?

Tags: webpack, prime-ui, css-loader

i use webpack to get Angular2 with PrimeNG running. PrimeNG has a dependency to PrimeUI which itself uses themes and in one of them (theme dark) there is an image missing (it is only used for old browser anyway).

But now when i use webpack to load the css file from it, it tells me "Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ...

How do i control from outside that css loader or sass loader (not sure who handles it at the end) should just ignore it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it helps, but there is missing an image in delta theme. It might work changing theme.
It might be an issue with webpack/primeui which I think is related to the reference to primeui's package.json: main: primeui-min.js

Comment: I opened an issue on github at PrimeUI about it and they fixed it. This does work but i was hoping more for a generic answer in case something like this happenes again.